# How to align multiple buttons inside a row in html?

Tags: css, html, button, tags

I am working on aligning two buttons to the middle of the row which is just below a table in the form.

But the alignment of buttons is vertical now. How do I make them horizontal and to the middle.

[This is how it is being displayed now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYyiL.png)

[For Joykal Infotech reference in IE after adding vendor prefixes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyf2g.png)

I want to align them properly to the middle of the row and the buttons should be on same axis. Return to Login should not be in multiple lines.

Here's what I tried.

```css
div.blueButton { /* Blue Button sized for submit */
            position:relative;
            margin:0;
            background:transparent url('../images/btn_blue_back.gif') repeat-x;
            color:white;
            padding:0 4px 6px 4px;
            text-align:center;
            width:45px;
            margin-left:520px;
        }
        div.blueButton_left {
            background:transparent url('../images/btn_blue_l.gif') no-repeat left;
            width:7px; height:22px;
            position:absolute;
            top:-2px; left:-2px;    
        }
        div.blueButton_right {
            background:transparent url('../images/btn_blue_r.gif') no-repeat right;
            width:7px; height:22px;
            position:absolute;
            top:-2px; right:-3px;   
        }

a.button, .button {
            width:auto;
            padding:0; margin:0 0 0 0;
            background:#005499;
            font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:white; text-decoration:none;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div>
<div class="blueButton">
<div class="blueButton_left"></div>
<div class="blueButton_right"></div>
<a href="" onclick="javascript:forgotUsername();return false;" class="button" onblur="javascript:f_setfocus();">Return to LogIn</a>
</div>
<div class="blueButton">
<div class="blueButton_left"></div>
<div class="blueButton_right"></div>
<a href="" onclick="javascript:forgotUsername();return false;" class="button" onblur="javascript:f_setfocus();">Continue</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need that structure? And that css is really not good written so if possible can you get rid of it? You could just use a simple text align center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, this might help
I have used a wrapper above both the buttons and provided `display: flex;` and `justify-content:center` and also removed the fixed `width` and `margin` given to `div.bluebutton`

And do checkout [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Update** - vendor prefixes added

```css
.wrap {
  -webkit-display: flex;
  -ms-display: flex;
  -o-display: flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  -o-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div.blueButton {
  /* Blue Button sized for submit */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent url('../images/btn_blue_back.gif') repeat-x;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 4px 6px 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.blueButton_left {
  background: transparent url('../images/btn_blue_l.gif') no-repeat left;
  width: 7px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

div.blueButton_right {
  background: transparent url('../images/btn_blue_r.gif') no-repeat right;
  width: 7px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: -3px;
}

a.button,
.button {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #005499;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="blueButton">
    <div class="blueButton_left"></div>
    <div class="blueButton_right"></div>
    <a href="" onclick="javascript:forgotUsername();return false;" class="button" onblur="javascript:f_setfocus();">Return to LogIn</a>
  </div>
  <div class="blueButton">
    <div class="blueButton_left"></div>
    <div class="blueButton_right"></div>
    <a href="" onclick="javascript:forgotUsername();return false;" class="button" onblur="javascript:f_setfocus();">Continue</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working as expected in Chrome and Firefox. But in IE, the buttons are still aligning vertically.

Comment: Please check the updated code i have added `-webkit-`  `-ms-`  `-o-` . these are the vendor prefixes

Comment: Tried vendor prefixes. But didn't work in IE - 11.0.9600.19230. It is still aligning the items vertically. Can there be any settings that I can check to correct the display?

Comment: [here](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox) see it should do the work, please share some picture of what you are getting. Also add `align-items: center;` to make them vertically aligned.

Comment: added the screenshot for your reference

Comment: I checked in IE 11.4 and works fine for me, and the vendor prefixes support `flex` after IE 10. So there must be some other issue, Have you checked the CSS, which I removed from the code?? and what CSS rules are setting them vertically, can you check in inspect element...

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap and take a div with class form-inline
and place both buttons inside div.
put the div in td where you want to display.

Comment: We are actually working old framewroks which were developed long ago. Is there any way to make this happen using pure html and css ?